# Exporting SQL Server to Excel - Too many posts?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, excel

I'm using this function to create an Excel file from my SQL Server query

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlConnection objcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

string sql = "My SELECT SQL";
SqlDataAdapter objda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, objcon);
objda.Fill(dt);

GridView gvreport = new GridView();
gvreport.DataSource = dt;
gvreport.DataBind();

string fileName = string.Format("fileNameHere");

Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gvreport.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();

return null;
```

Which worked great until I now realized that it does not work so well when its trying to write over 11,000 rows.

The Excel file itself is fine but after around 11,000 rows it suddenly breaks during one and after that all rows are blank. The rows themselves are still "created" with an border and everything but they are all blank.

Any idea what is causing this? Or is there any better way to create an Excel file like this?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @davisoa to create or read? I am using the openoffice one to read while I am not certain what the code is using to create.

Comment: A google search on "Apache POI" will lead to a different way.  You can decide whether or not it's better.

Comment: The first thing I'd look at is whether something somewhere is timing out, or hitting some sort of size limit on request/response size.

Comment: @davisoa Actually. I just tried opening with MS Office 2010 and it could read all posts fine, the issue lied with openoffice. Well this got fixed in an odd way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in your case you are not actually generating a real Excel file, just plain HTML and telling Excel to open it and convert it. You may encounter other problems using this approach with OpenOffice or LibreOffice or any other tool that actually expects a real Excel file.

I would look into a more robust solution, by using either [OpenXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180830%28v=office.14%29.aspx) directly, or indirectly through [ClosedXml](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) or some other similar component.

For example, if you were to use ClosedXml, you can do something like this:

```
var wb = new XLWorkbook();

var dataTable = GetTable("Information");

// Add a DataTable as a worksheet
wb.Worksheets.Add(dataTable);

wb.SaveAs("AddingDataTableAsWorksheet.xlsx");
```

Extracted from: https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Adding%20DataTable%20as%20Worksheet

However, in your case instead of saving to a physical file you'd output the stream directly to the Response.

Comment: Are there any that works similar to mine? i.e so I can use my already predefined SQL or am I gonna have to create classes?

Comment: Just added an example, taken from the ClosedXml documentation